# Granting datalab access to another project

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-datalab

I have Datalab running on one Google Cloud project (lets call it `A`), I have data sitting in another project (`B`). I'd like to grant Datalab access to this data.

I note that Datalab uses my projects "Compute Engine default" service account - I assume I can authorize this account in my second project (`B`) to grant Datalab access to the data within it. Is this considered the best practice approach and are there any other considerations I should keep in mind?

Answer (score 1):

The right way to do is exactly what you think. 
Go to 'IAM and admin' -> 'Admin' then choose your service account and a role for this project.

Keep in mind that project has been created to create security on accessibility. Sometimes having replicated data is not a bad idea. Really depends on the need.